Are there any negative impact if access to directories were accidently denied?
Are there any negative impact if I add the following a rewrite rule on my Wordpress installation?
I am using Apache Web Server and Wordpress 6.6.2.

Note: That RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d is absent from the rule.


My intention: is to return 404 for all request not looking for an existing file. Thus negating access to directories too. I don't want public to peek through directory structure.


My concern: is that this rule, which also deny access to directories, could potentially disrupt WordPress functionality or usage.

    
    # /wordpress/.htaccess
    
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # return 404 for all request not looking for an existing file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wordpress/(wp-content|wp-includes)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
    </IfModule>



do you have removed this line by editing the .htaccess file ? if it's the case, the line can be regenerated by wordpress and you need to use a filter to remove it.

Normally you prevent directory listings via the Options -Indexes directive. Is there some reason that this is insufficient for your use-case?

@mmm This block stood outside Wordpress parameter (not in between #BEGIN Wordpress and #END Wordpress) . @bosco .. then i guess, this question will lead to server configuration. I should look into my localhost server config. Thanks a lot.

No, this should not have a negative effect – but it is also unnecessary if the hosting is set up correctly. Calling up non-existent URLs should always lead to a 404. Directories can be an exception if the DirectoryListing is not deactivated for them in the hosting – then you could see a list of all files in the directory when calling them. You should check this and adjust it if necessary.
If you're using Apache Web Server then look into httpd.conf or config.ini then change Options Indexes to Options -Indexes
    Options -Indexes

    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # FollowSymLinks is the default setting.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #

Or you can add Options -Indexes to your .htaccess file at the root directory of your website.
Options -Indexes

Difference is, one is handled at server level, the other is at website level.
